# What is "Rapid" in reference to the MSN Games GDK?

Tags: microsoft

I have herd a little talk about the MSN Games GDK lately, and what wondering what **Rapid** was.

It sounds like some sort of testing environment, is this true? How can I get access to it? Or find out more about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From some old (2006/2007) presentation on MSN Games...

RAPID!

- Integration Test Tool
- Allows
  developers to test that the MSN API
  is correctly implemented
- It does not:

  - Verify client requirements
  - Doesn't
    test the game play

Links to the main site is here [MSN Games](http://zone.msn.com/en/microsoftcasualgames/resources.htm) and the developer resources are [here](http://zone.msn.com/en/microsoftcasualgames)

To get access to the developer libs you'll need to submit a concept, have it approved and then take it from there. (I've not actually done any of this so can't advise you on the process itself).